# How do I change meanio so that it points to mongo at a different port/address?

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, mean.io

I've installed meanio and setup a project folder. I can use grunt to run the project and it works fine. I'm having an issue trying to find where to change the mongodb address and port so I do not have to use mongo locally and at a different port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the port in the config folder. For example to **config/env/development.js** and open the file. The code will look like this:

```
module.exports = {
db: 'mongodb://localhost/mean-dev',
app: {
    name: 'MEAN - FullStack JS - Development'
},
```

You will need to make to changes

1) edit the db location to the proper mongodb database

2) add the port you'd like to run it on

```
module.exports = {
db: 'mongodb://localhost/your-mongodb-name',
port: 6000,
app: {
    name: 'MEAN - FullStack JS - Development'
},
```

You can make these changes for each app environmentincluding production and test